Is there a way to store an array of ObjectIds uniquely?
I'm creating a messaging schema and would like to ensure that the (aggregated) participants are stored uniquely (i.e. the two participants in a thread, stored as object Ids cannot be duplicated).
Would the ideal way just be to store them in a particular order, or is there a better way to achieve this with MongoDB/Mongoose?

If the participants are in an array like this one:
{
  _id: ObjectId('672275001d85fdc2c6a91035'),
  partcipants: [
    ObjectId('672275001d85fdc2c6a91033'),
    ObjectId('672275001d85fdc2c6a91034')
  ]
}

Creating an index on participants with the unique restriction will make impossible to add another document with an array containing those two ObjectIds in that order

Thank you. So, just to confirm, there's no way to do this without ensuring the ObjectIds are in the same order?

If there's only two ids you can use find to check if they existed in either order, using an OR with id1, id2 OR id2, id1
